# How to get versions in package.xml from roscpp codes

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I would like to know if there is a way to get versions inside roscpp codes.
I want to print out the software version of node when it is launched, automatically referring manifest file.
Any hints, comments are welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231956/how-to-get-versions-in-package.xml-from-roscpp-codes/) by [okku](https://answers.ros.org/users/26594/okku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Buried [deep in the catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html) there is a note that after calling `catkin_pacakge()`, the package version is available as a cmake variable that is named after your package:  `<packagename>_VERSION`

You could make this available to C++ code using the add_definitions cmake command, like:

```
catkin_package(
    # any arguments to catkin_package here
)

add_definitions("-D${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION=\"${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}\"")
```

This uses the -D option to the compiler, which is equivalent to a `#define`.

You could use the version in your code as a string, for example:

```
ROS_INFO("Package version is %s", mypackage_VERSION); // replace mypackage with your package name
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [okku](https://answers.ros.org/users/26594/okku/) on 2016-04-25**:
Cool! This is what I wanted.
Worked perfectly on my ROS Indigo environment.